# Netlogo - "agents-here" not behaving as expected

Tags: netlogo, patch, neighbours

Thank you for earlier input on my question. In this model the boat moves diagonally across the world (which does not wrap, 00 bottom left, max-pycor & max-pxcor 49) and 20 fish move in the opposite diagonal. It is the intention that the boat counts the fish it encounters (i.e. the b-count increases) and the fish turn yellow. When the fish moves off the same patch as the boat, it changes color back to blue. To verify the boat counts, each fish records when it meets the boat, (i.e. the f-count increases) and the fish change shape from star to circle. Again when the fish is no longer on the same patch as the boat, the fish change back to a star shape. It does not matter if the boat does not meet all the fish.

On this specific run, random seed is set, when "boat 0" and "fish 18" encounter each other (inspecting both and at tick 183), they appear to be on the same patch, but the relevant counts do not increase and "fish 18" does not change shape or color. As a beginner with NetLogo, is there something in the coding of "boats-here", "fish-here" or "neighbors" that I am overlooking that is related to the xcor/ycor of the agents? Or is the sequence of commands the source of the problem? Thanks once again for considering my question.

```
    globals [ starting-seed ]
    
    breed [boats boat]
    breed [fish a-fish]

    boats-own [b-count fuel]
    fish-own [f-count]

    to setup
      clear-all
      set starting-seed 91130056
      random-seed starting-seed
      reset-ticks

    create-boats 1
      [apply-boat-properties]

     create-fish 20
      [apply-fish-properties]

    end

    to apply-boat-properties
      ask boats
      [
        set color red
        set size 0.3
        set shape "star"
        setxy min-pxcor max-pycor
        set fuel 710
      ]
    end

    to apply-fish-properties
      ask fish
      [
        set color blue
        set size 0.3
        set shape "star"
        setxy random-xcor max-pycor
      ]
    end


    to go
     if (any? boats with [fuel <= 0 ])
      [ stop ]

      ask boats
      [
        follow-route1
        survey
      ]

      ask fish
      [
        check-if-boat
        move
      ]

      tick

    end


    to follow-route1
      ask boats
    [
        facexy 49 0
        fd 0.05
        pen-down
        set fuel fuel - 1
      ]
    end


    to survey
      ifelse any? fish-here                     ;; if boat on the same patch as a fish
      [ask fish-here [                          ;; ask the fish on this patch
        if shape = "star"[                      ;; with a "star" shape
          set shape "circle"                    ;; change shape to "circle" shape
       ask boats-here                           ;; ask boat on same patch to increase b-count
  [set b-count b-count + 1]]
      ]
      ]
                                                   ;; otherwise
        [ask fish-on neighbors [                   ;; ask fish on neighbouring 8 patches
          if shape = "circle"[                     ;; if the fish has a "circle" shape
            set shape "star" ]                     ;; change that shape to "star" shape
      ]]
    end


    to move
      ask fish
     [
        set heading 225
        fd 0.0025

      ]
    end

    to check-if-boat
      ifelse any? boats-here                     ;; if boats on same patch as the fish
      [
          ask fish-here with [color = blue]      ;; ask the blue fish to change to yellow
        [ set color yellow
          set f-count f-count + 1]               ;; and increase f-count by 1
      ]
      [ask fish-here with [color = yellow]       ;; otherwise ask yellow fish to go blue
          [set color blue
    ] ]

    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific example, they simply are not on the same patch. Fish 18 is on 7 43 while the boat is on 6 43. You can check this quickly by using `ask boat 0 [show patch-here]`. At tick 184, they have crossed into 6 42 and 7 42 respectively, neither one ever stepping on the same patch.

Another problem I see is that sometimes a fish changes color but not shape.
The problem here is the order in which things happen. Currently it is:
The boat moves => the boat scans => the fish move => the fish scan.
Because of this, a fish can move onto a patch after the boat has already scanned that patch and determined there was no fish there. Or a fish can move off of a patch and no longer see that boat that scanned it.
Simply changing this to boat moves => the fish move => the boat scans => the fish scan will solve this issue.

There is currently also an edge case where a boat and fish could move away from eachother simultanously, causing the boat to be unable to set the fishes shape back to star.

Comment: Thank you LeirsW, I was looking at the xcor and ycor of the boat 0 and a-fish 18 rather than the patch, but can now see with "show patch-here" that they do miss each other. Thank you also for identifying the issue with the sequence of procedures, which makes absolute sense, but I did not know how to resolve either. It's obvious now of course! Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Hi LeirsW, ran my Behaviour Experiment on the model with the changes your suggested and got 100% alignment between both sets of counts, so very happy. Thanks so much for your help.